# Batchable class variable shows as NULL in finish() method

Tags: apex, batch, global-variables, global-methods

Sorry if the format is not good, first post ever and I don't know what all the options are.

totalRecords list size is printing as NULL in the email message body, I cannot figure out why.

```
global class errorRecordsCleanUp_batch implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {

    global Integer totalRecords;

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<ErrorRecords__c> scope) {

        List<ErrorRecords__c> errorList = new List<ErrorRecords__c>();

        for(ErrorRecords__c element:scope) {
            errorList.add(element);
        }

        try {
            totalRecords = errorList.size();
            System.debug('####totalRecords size: ' + totalRecords);
            **//this debug statement if printing out the correct totalRecords size no problem**
        }

        …//rest of the class
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    String body = 'Hello,<br/><br/>Batch process to delete errors records from ErrorRecords__c table has been completed. <br/><br/>' + 'Total deleted records: ' + totalRecords;
    **//this string in printing totalRecords as NULL in the email message body, why is that?**
    …//rest of the class
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a "marker" interface `Database.Stateful` that alters the way the framework manages the batchable class and ensures that fields are preserved between `execute` calls and through into the `finish` method.

Adding that to the class signature will fix the problem in part:

```
... implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {
```

and you also need to change these lines:

```
Integer totalRecords = 0;
...
totalRecords += errorList.size();
```

to sum the records from the multiple calls to `execute`.

See the "Using State in Batch Apex" section of [Using Batch Apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm).

Comment: This solved the problem, thank you! Sorry I couldn't vote up apparently I'm too new to vote.